# How i can sort space delimiter string in a file?

Tags: c#, regex, sorting

I have a file delimited string  by space

```
44 34 56 25 

18 3  50 23

19 21 34 08
```

and output this

```
25 34 44 56

3 18  23 50 

08 19 21 34
```

Code

```
string   content = File.ReadAllText("finalregex2.txt");

string[] lines = Regex.Split(content, "( )+");

Array.Sort(lines);
```

I'm trying to sort but I don't know how complete this command

please help me to complete my  command

> cs0117 string doesn contain definition

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {           
        var result = File.ReadAllLines("finalregex2.txt")
                         .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                         .Select(line => string.Join(" ", line.Split( new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                               .OrderBy(value => int.Parse(value))))
                         .ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `string[] lines = content.Split(' ');` instead of a Regex?

Comment: @Tim To treat consecutive spaces as one? Although `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` takes care of that.

Comment: you'll need to `Split` each string in `lines` and sort them by their parsed integer value.  Look up `string.Split` and `int.Parse`.

Comment: @GSerg - Didn't notice the consecutive spaces at first glance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of useing `ReadAllText` use `ReadAllLines` and then use `.Split` on each line:

```
var result = File.ReadAllLines("finalregex2.txt")
                 .Select(line => string.Join(" ", line.Split( new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                       .OrderBy(value => int.Parse(value)))).ToList();
```

If also in your real file you have empty lines between those with the numbers then add between the `ReadAllLines` and the `Select`:

```
.Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
```

Comment: cs0117    string doesn contain definition

Comment: @jhonny625 - I just copied the code you pasted into a clean project and it compiled... These compilation errors are not related..

Comment: @jhonny625 - you are missing there both the namespace and the `main` is private.. change it to `public static void Main(string[] args)`...

Comment: not but i think your answer is wright  ;if there is no other answer tomorrow I chose you as best answer
by the time I found another solution to my problem

Comment: i think the problem It could be a compatibility problem with my compiler

Comment: im using sharp developer 3.2